# Getting an error about WebSocket from RavenDB on IIS/Windows Server 2016

Tags: iis, websocket, ravendb-studio

I'm trying to running RavenDB from IIS on Windows Server 2016. I've followed [Installation : Running as an IIS application](https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/3.5/http/server/installation/IIS). It's running but gives an error.

> **Error Title:** Your server doesn't support the WebSocket protocol!
>
> **Error Details:** EventSource API is going to be used instead. However, multi tab usage isn't supported.
> WebSockets are only supported on servers running on Windows Server 2012 and equivalent. 
> If you have issues with WebSockets on Windows Server 2012 and equivalent use Status > Debug > WebSocket to debug.

I've installed **WebSocket Protocol** in my Server. [IIS 8.0 WebSocket Protocol Support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-8/iis-80-websocket-protocol-support)

I've tried to follow the debugging suggestion **Status > Debug > WebSocket to debug.** and found:

> Connecting to web socket using url: ws://0.0.0.0:83/databases/Demo/websocket/validate?singleUseAuthToken=8b463931-7dab-4783-ad26-211ad538becb&id=test&coolDownWithDataLoss=1000&isMultyTenantTransport=false
> Server doesn't support web sockets protocol
> WebSocket disconnected in unclean way

Please help to solve this error.
Thanks for your time and consideration.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable the WebSocket protocol on the server:

Add Roles and Features > Server Roles > Web Server (IIS) > Web Server > Application Development > WebSocket Protocol

[image]

Comment: I've installed this feature but it's not solve the issue.